# How to git clone in intellij

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I tried to upload my project to the Git server, so I made a Git clone like the picture below.

(Not Git Hub, only Git Server)

[image]

I expected a project to be created in the picture above so that all classes in the Directory, configuration files (build.gradle, etc.) could be committed to the git server, but an empty project was created as shown in the picture below

How can I transfer my source code that I've worked on so far to the project in the picture below?

[image]

Comment: The problem might be in the path - looks like slashes are not there, and this might cause issues. Do the project actually gets cloned, and the source are present on disk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure your Directory include \

```
C:\Workspace\...
# not
C:Workspace...
```

Second, when [cloning a repository from the main menu﻿](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/cloning-repository.html#clone_project_from_main_screen), make sure the target directory does not exist or is empty.